# Multiple IMAP accounts in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

I have 3 different IMAP accounts defined on my Outlook 2007,

They are all listed on the left hand side and I can switch between them, the default one is 'Account1'

The problem is that when I'm in Account2 or Account3 and I try to compose a new message, the 'sender' is defined to Account1 as it's the default account.

Also, the signature of Account1 is shown.

Is there a way to define that when I'm composing a message while on Account2/Account3 that the sender email will be the correct one (account2/account3) and also to load the correct signature accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Start composing a new message and then select "Show From" from the toolbar.  This will add a dropdown list to the message which will allow you to select the account you are sending the message from.  From that moment, the From dropdown list will appear on each message you compose.

You can also set a single account as your "default" from within the account list (the area where you add new accounts).  Setting a default account will determine which selection is automatically made in that dropdown list when you compose a new message.

Comment: Hi Fred thank you for your response. I am aware of what you've said (also described this behavior in my question body). I don't understand why Outlook is not 'smart' enough to know that I'm replying a message sent to Account2 and therefore automatically choose Account2 as the sender for that particular message..

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of MS Office 2007 is to use the Sent To email address when replying.  You might have something corrupted if it is not working that way.  To check, you could perform the following

1. Shutdown Outlook and then copy/move the current PST file to somewhere safe.
2. Use the Control Panel Mail applet and delete all the Outlook accounts.
3. Setup the account you wish to be the default with a new data file.
4. Setup the other account with a separate new data file.
5. Open Outlook.
6. Open the OLD PST file using File | Open | Open Outlook data file.
7. Once the file is open you can drag and drop items to the appropriate spots in your new data files.

Outlook should then act as you desire. In whichever Inbox you are working Outlook should use that account as the reply account.  If you reply to an email then the Sent To should be used as the From email address.